# Passing a pipefd through execlp in C

Tags: process, pipe, fork, parent-child

I have looked all over and I cannot seem to figure out how to do this.

I have a parent process that has created a pipe()

Now, I want to fork() the parent and then execlp() and pass the pipe() to the new program as a command line argument.

Then from inside the new program I need to be able to read the pipefd.

I've seen a bunch of stuff on how to do it from inside the same process, but nothing on how to do it like this.

Edit: Initial post is/was rather vague.

What I have so far is:

```
int pfd[2];
     if(pipe(pfd) == -1) {
             perror("Creating pipe\n");
             exit(1);
     }
pid_t pid = fork();
if(pid == -1) {
             fprintf (stderr, "Initiator Error Message : fork failed\n");
             return -1;
     }
else if(pid == 0) {  // child process
             close(pipe0[1]);        // close(write);

             execlp("program", "program", pipe0[0], NULL);
     }
```

but then I don't really understand what I should do from inside "program" to get the FD. I tried assigning it to all sorts of things, but they all seem to error.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's stopping you from doing that exactly? Where are you running into trouble? Do you know what `dup2` does and how to use it?

Comment: I can't figure out how to pickup the fd in the child program.

Comment: What do you mean by passing the fd as an argument?

Comment: @lexIcon There's nothing special the child program needs to do. Everything should be arranged before you call `execlp`.

Answer (score 0):

The forked and execed child automatically inherit the open pipe descriptors and the pipe output is usually fed as standard input so that a command line argument to find the pipe is pretty redundant:

```
if(!pipe(&pipefd))
  switch(fork()) {
  case  0: !dup2(pipefd[0],0)&&
           execlp("cat","cat","-n","/dev/fd/0",0);
  case -1: return perror("fork");
  default: write(pipefd[1],"OK\n",3);
}
```